# Running npm run watch from route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-artisan

I am building a cms in laravel and was wondering if it's possible to use the command npm run watch from a route?

I've found out that it's easy to use php artisan commands but can't find anything about building a command to compile assets from a route.

Really hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I have found out that I can use the php exec or shell_exec(to get also the output) but is this a save way of working?

Comment: Please pay an attention to tags. [tag:elixir] is a brilliant programming language having nothing to do with php artisans. You might consider adding [tag:laravel-elixir] instead.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't do that, use `npm run build` instead, before deploy on stage xor production